problem installing updates
I have Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. I have been unable to update applications that are not included in snaps. I have downloaded the latest deb files for Chrome, Microsoft Edge, etc., but I cannot find a way to replace the versions on my hard drive with these newer updated versions. If I try to use App Center, it tells me that the apps are in fact installed, but gives me no way to update them. If I try to use Software Updates, there is no option to recognize the deb files at all.


How did you install the .deb files?  For example, did you use apt or apt-get from the command line? // 2) On my system, Google Chrome also added a file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d, pointing to Google's repo for Chrome.  That way, Chrome gets updates automatically.


If you have the .deb files you should install them manually on the command line with sudo apt install /path/to/file replacing the /path/to/file with the actual path to your .deb files.  Note the Microsoft .deb will just install the MS repositories and then install from those automatically, they don't actually install much else because that's how it keep things updated.  Same for Chrome.

Snaps are (I am simplifying this) packages that Snap Store or Software Center will download and install for you when you click the install button; Hence they are able to keep a list of installed applications, check and notify you when there is an update.
Files ending with .deb however, are programs you install, not the Software Center, so they cannot keep track of it and tell you when there is an update. For these kinds of applications, you have to check the source every once in a while to download and install newer versions, using apt.
Luckily, some applications (for example VScode or Chrome) add a file to apt's directory, giving it the ability to look up updates for that application, they same way it does for system packages. To do that, you will first need to update the list of applications that apt can automatically download, by running sudo apt update in the terminal.
Here, I have added a file myself to download the latest version of Firefox; Yours might be different:
sudo apt update              
....
Get:4 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla InRelease [1,522 B]             
Get:5 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages [98.8 kB]
Get:6 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main i386 Packages [97.9 kB]
Get:7 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main all Packages [5,669 kB]
Fetched 6,018 kB in 6s (990 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
73 packages can be upgraded.

On the last line, for me, it says there are 73 programs that apt can download a newer version for; If yours says that there are upgrades to do, you can install them by running sudo apt upgrade in you terminal.
Keep in mind though, not all applications can or will do this. In case they don't, you have to install updates manually: First go to the source that you got the .deb file from, and get the newer version, then install it the same way you installed it the first time, by running sudo apt install <path-to-file>.deb. By doing this, apt will upgrade your program to the newer version.
